# How to communicate with a USB device under Windows and Java?

Tags: java, windows, usb

I'd like to communicate with a USB device under Windows and Java but I can't find a good library to do so. I don't want the user to have to install any extra hardware or device drivers to make this work. That is, I want to be able to interact with USB just like other Windows applications do.

I am familiar with jUSB and JSR 80 but both seem to be dead projects (at least for Windows).

Comment: I just found this at http://cafe.elharo.com/blogroll/what-java-still-cant-do/#comment-69109 "[...] on Windows, you cant just list connected devices and start talking to them, which is what the Java USB API is for." I don't fully understand his comment but it sounds rather discouraging :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did quite a bit of research on this some time ago, and the unfortunate fact was that all the useful free USB+Windows+Java projects were dead. There is commercial and expensive (price $39.99 is not per developer, but per copy of your software sold!) [JCommUSB](http://www.icaste.com/) library which probably works, although I have no experience of it; we had to build our own custom C wrappers to the USB drivers and communicate with them through JNI.

Comment: Looks like the JCommUSB library is dead as well.The domain name is up for sale.

Answer (score 9):

libusb-win32 requires you to install their generic driver, which then makes a USB device available to you.  I'm not sure that it's possible to do driver-less access of an USB device unless the device belongs to one of several standard classes (storage and HID, in particular).

There is a [Java wrapper for libusb-win32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusbjava/) which might work for you.  I haven't used it myself, though.

Comment: Don't all USB devices ship with on-board drivers which get installed automatically when you plug the device in? Or is this just for "standard" devices?

Is it at least possible to communicate with "standard" devices using Java without drivers?

Comment: No, on-board drivers are an exception. Standard devices, such as storage and HID (keyboards, mouses etc.) would probably work with the above mentioned libusb-win32. Windows includes standard drivers for them.

Comment: I have been looking for a simple way to interact with a custom USB device that didn't involve emulating a comm port, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The fastest and easiest way is to hack some native code :) 
I wrote a small wrapper for HID devices that enabled my Java applications to read data from CalComp digitizers, so it's definitely doable and not too hard. The bad thing is that my work is still proprietary code owned by my former employer, so for legal reasons I can't release that as open-source -- yet.

The good thing is that you can get a flying start with the HID example code from the Microsoft DDK :)

Answer (score 0):

Communication between Windows and a USB device by java.
http://javausbapi.blogspot.com/2010/05/java-usb-api.html

An example is conducted for a Freescale microcontroller