# How can I use Java to communicate to device through USB port?

Tags: java, usb, mobile-devices

I just recently learn Java and try to communicate to the device through USB port connection.  I've have used C# with OpenNETCF which allows me to send file and retrieve file on the device through USB port;  how can I achieve this with java?

I seearch on stackoverflow thread, [How to communicate with a USB device under Windows and Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544507/how-to-communicate-with-a-usb-device-under-windows-and-java), the comment made by christoffer is to hack the native code, but I don't quite which native code api that he referred to.  RAPI, maybe?

Answer (score 3):

The only USB API I could find for Windows [is here](http://www.steelbrothers.ch/jusb/).  Seems as if it has limited functionality, but it might suit your needs.  A more complete [UNIX API](http://jusb.sourceforge.net/) is also available.

**ETA**: Found a link to the official [Java USB implementation](http://javax-usb.org/), but looks like the windows version is still in alpha.

Comment: The above link to *javax-usb.org* is dead. However I found these two: [javax.usb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javax-usb/) (This seems to be the official one) and [javax-usb-libusb1](https://github.com/trygvis/javax-usb-libusb1)

Answer (score 0):

The native code API I referred to was the Windows DDK, i.e. the Driver Development Kit. The modern version seem to be called Windows Driver Kit, so google for Windows WDK :)
There should be a few C samples on how to communicate with USB devices, and it should be pretty straightforward to write a JNI wrapper from those.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick thought, you could use JNI, the Java Native Interface. I've never used it myself though.

Answer (score 0):

I found this page that explains how to perform a communication between a microcontroller and a java application: http://javausbapi.blogspot.com/

Answer (score -1):

The Best way I found to communicate with USB is through RxTx library.

You can find an example of the usage here:
http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/1044/Java--read-from-USB-using-RXTX-library