# Java USB library

Tags: java, api, usb

Is there a good Java USB API i can use? I tried JUSB but it doesn't seem to work. It's also very old, no updates since 2001.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644241/how-can-i-use-java-to-communicate-to-device-through-usb-port and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444497/using-java-and-usb-which-api-jsr-80-jusb

Comment: USB communication example through a java application.
http://javausbapi.blogspot.com/2010/05/java-usb-api.html
Excellent!!

Answer (score 2):

About two years ago I used [Java libusb](http://libusbjava.sourceforge.net/wp/) with success. It has the advantage that you are not limited to special device classes like HID.

Comment: Java libusb looks really old too.  It only supports libusb 0.1, while libusb 1.0 has been out for many years and is a lot better.  Also, it does not support WinUSB, which is the simplest driver solution for a vendor-specific Windows USB device.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](https://launchpad.net/libusb4j). It uses [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/) so potentially it is more "hackable" than any JNI-based library

Answer (score 1):

I used [usb4java](http://usb4java.org/). On Windows, I installed WinUSB driver and it appeared to work
Google: usb4java
The advantage is high-level usb api. so the program is virtually portable to different lib. (not only usb4java)