# Best working Java API for USB connection

Tags: java, smartcard-reader

I want to get the serial number of a smart card reader connected to pc via USB. One way to do this is to get the `iSerialNumber` of the USB (smart card reader). Can anyone please guide me about the best working Java API for this purpose?

Should work in windows 7 as well. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/862880/java-usb-library

Comment: Thanks @AVD. I read the thread and its not actually fit for my purpose!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I've come up with is to query WMI through C++ and then use its DLL in Java through JNI.

Answer (score 0):

There is the jUSB API which you could use. Documentation [here](http://jusb.sourceforge.net/apidoc/usb/core/DeviceDescriptor.html#getSerialStringId%28%29)

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this API. Its kind of difficult to set it up. If you can help me setting up, it would really be appreciated.

Comment: Windows installation instructions can be found [here](http://www.steelbrothers.ch/jusb/api/usb/windows/related-docs/chp8-developerinstallation.pdf). The original project page [here](http://www.steelbrothers.ch/jusb/) I haven't tried it personally, so I'm not sure if this will work on windows 7.