# USB Java libraries

Tags: java, usb, libusb

I am developing several data logger application which must connect with the USB dongle in order to read/write information. That is to say, I have to send commands to the USB port and the application should be able to read streams from the usb dongle. My doubt is about JAva libraries for implementing this interface and functionality. As yet, I was using a FTDI one but it is out-dated and it only works with Windows 32 bits. With the new Windows Operating Systems 64 bits it does not work. Could you recommend me some USB library for Java?

Thank you very much in advance,
Nice day

Comment: What relates this to java-ee?

Comment: not the first time this came up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/862880/java-usb-library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out the following link for downloading libraries

Java USB Library.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/javausblibrary/