# I want to listen for data on a usb port using java.....any api?

Tags: java

I want to listen for data on a *usb* port using java.....any API ???
I searched Google and found "

> JUSB

" but it is too old and some other too.all
are too old .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java USB library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/862880/java-usb-library)

Comment: Try libusb, it has support for all languages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can try [libusb](https://launchpad.net/libusb4j).** It is based on JNA though

There is also [javahidapi](https://code.google.com/p/javahidapi/)

Comment: JNI is cross-pltform.

Comment: I need to read data from a heamatology analyzer and some other devices who send data,can u give me some simple java solution..

Comment: I am using windows xp,7,8