# Question on converting HID to MIDI

Tags: midi, hid

I was wondering if anyone had some suggestions for converting HID signals to MIDI signals... what I have is a U-HID board and since it sends HID signals to my computer I can't use the analog capabilities (like the potentiometers) of it in other programs that are not HID friendly but do like MIDI.

So what I was wondering is if anyone could point me in the direction for making this HID board  work with MIDI friendly probrams. such as intermediate programs

I run a Windows Vista operating system.
the link to the board I'm using is http://www.u-hid.com/home/index.php 
the program I would like to use this board for is Traktor ( it can be found at the native instruments home page... transparently I can't post more than one link... but it is a digital djing program). Traktor does not support vst plugins either.

I have basic knowledge of the C programming language and have been messing with java.

Thanks, 
Jesse

Answer (score 1):

you could take a look at the generic virtual MIDI
driver I have developed for Windows:

http://www.tobias-erichsen.de/virtualMIDI.html

This driver has a simple user-space API to create
freely nameable MIDI-ports on Windows systems
from XP up to W7, both 32 and 64 bit.

This driver is used in my rtpMIDI network midi driver
and my loopMIDI virtual midi cable (and in some 3rd
party products as well)

Best regards,
Tobias

Comment: Jesse, Tobias' driver is excellent for then outputting your messages to a MIDI input on the machine without using extra loopback software.  (I use it myself)  However, it doesn't have anything to do with the root of what you are trying to accomplish.  Just keep in mind that you still need to write the code to handle HID.

Answer (score 0):

HID report types are different from device to device.  While HID is a standard protocol, it is very low level.  You won't find a higher-level standard, and thus no software to universally convert HID to MIDI.

You may however be able to write a program to support this board.  (In fact, if I had such a board, I'd love to tackle this challenge.)

I recommend using http://sourceforge.net/projects/usbsnoop/ to help debug.  I've used this software to figure out HID on credit card readers, and to debug [software that interfaces with Wii Remotes](http://wiimotelib.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I'm somewhat new to programming. I've only had two classes in C programming. I'm trying to learn java. What language would you suggest that I start with?

Comment: Also, with the snoopy program, I was having issues with it, and already e-mailed them for help.

Comment: but does it basically look or "sniff" for a usb device connected to your computer?

Comment: Yes, it shows you the data flowing between the device and the computer.  Put it on your mouse and watch the packets, to get an idea.  You can use whatever language you want to use.  See this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544507/how-to-communicate-with-a-usb-device-under-windows-and-java/545278#545278