# how to get the details of USB devices connected to computer using java

Tags: java, swing, usb, hardware, jusb

I am trying to get the details of USB hardware devices connected to computer but I don't know the native code of windows so is it possible to get the details of hardware connected to computer using JAVA Thanks in advance

vbscript code:

```
Set HDs = GetObject("winmgmts:(impersonationLevel=impersonate)")
Set colItem=HDs.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_DiskDrive")
For Each hd In colItem
    Wscript.Echo hd.PnPDeviceID & "vigi"
Next
```

java code:

```
try {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cscript //NoLogo " + file.getPath());
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        result += line;
    }
    input.close();
} catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

now i'm trying to get the details using this vbscipt code but when i'm executing this code the error comes no script found

Comment: There is already a post about this.

Check [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980509/enumerate-external-drives

Comment: have you tried looking at the answers provided here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544507/how-to-communicate-with-a-usb-device-under-windows-and-java

Comment: @PrateekJain @Radai, format for links in comments `[TEXT](URL)` :)

Comment: i've used the vbscript to find the details of USB device but somehow i can't execute that vbscript the error comes no scrpit found

Answer (score 1):

Try using JUsb. The link [here](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/07/06/java-and-usb.html) provides simple example.