# I want to send and recieve data over CP2102 using Java

Tags: java

i'm trying to connect to CP2102 UART Bridge to send and receive data 
how can i implement that in java

Answer (score 2):

In general you cannot (or *should not*) do that in Java - [CP2102](http://www.silabs.com/products/interface/usbtouart/Pages/usb-to-uart-bridge.aspx) is a USB-to-serial device and Java is not very good at talking to USB devices, at least not out-of-the-box, portably and without reliability issues.

Admittedly, a large part of that has to do with the difficulties of userspace USB drivers in general, but Java makes quite a few things even more difficult. In addition, you would have to write a Java driver for your bridge chip, which is generally *not* an easy task.

In your place I would just install the CP2102 drivers for my operating system and use the device as a normal serial port, e.g. with [RXTX](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).

If you *do* insist of talking to the USB chip directly, you could prepare yourself for a long and tiring process and have a look at these:

- [How to access USB ports in java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2121508/507519)
- [How to communicate with a USB device under Windows and Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/544507/507519)
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-usb/index.html

Comment: mmm what i'm trying to do exactly is to pass sequence of bytes to a pic with the CP2102
so do you think that i shouldn't do it with java directly ?

Comment: @C.e.Abdullah: no, install the driver for your OS and use it as a serial port - that should be more than sufficient