# Can we get VID and PID from USB Flash drive in java?

Tags: java, usb-flash-drive

I have a requirement to get VID and PID of removable Flash Drive in java? I have googled a lot I can not get any proper answer. Many of the communities there are few instructions but there is no proper instructions, which packages I have to import. Among most of the answer are written in C++.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Java does not allow low level communications directly with hardware (or other OS specific calls). There might be libraries out there that could help you, but that would require native libraries and/or JNI calls and code written in a lower level language (such as C/C++). What operating system are you targeting?

Comment: The answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544507/how-to-communicate-with-a-usb-device-under-windows-and-java) are still valid. Java just does not allow such low level communication. There a are a few links to old projects that might still have some useful code for you.

Answer (score -1):

Java does not allow communication to hardware (such as USB devices) on any platform.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544507/how-to-communicate-with-a-usb-device-under-windows-and-java) has some links to defunct and other old projects that attempt to provide JNI library wrappers for such functionality.